# Pareto distribution is macroeconomic

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

In an article, the author define a Pareto Distribution. He gives us some hint that:

- The Pareto CDF is $F(z)=\operatorname{Prob}\{Z \leq z\}=1-T^\theta z^{-\theta}$ and the associated PDF is $\theta T^\theta z^{-\theta-1}$. The expected value is $\frac{\theta}{\theta-1} T$. Throughout the examples we normalize the parameter $T=1$.
- The expected value, conditional on being at or above the value $\hat{x}$, is $\frac{\theta}{\theta-1} \hat{x}$.
- The logarithm of $\frac{z}{\hat{x}}$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $\theta$. This implies that the expected value of $\log \left(\frac{z}{\hat{x}}\right)$ is $\frac{1}{\theta}$.

Then, he calculate the $\int \log z f(z) d z$ and says the result is $1/\theta$, i totally have no idea how he get this result and i am seeking for help. Can anyboby tell me how he get this result?

He also calculate $\int_{\hat{z}} f\left(z \mid Z \geq \hat{z}_i\right) d z$ and $\hat{z}$ is a value. The result of this function is $\frac{\theta}{\theta-1}$. Is that because of the second point he mentioned? If it is true, why the second point can get this value?

Comment: Hi! What is $\hat{z}_i$ in the second question ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very interesting problem. For $\theta,T>0$, the Pareto density is defined by:

$$\forall z\geq T, f(z) = \frac{\theta T^\theta}{z^{\theta+1}}.$$

You want to compute then:

$$I\triangleq \int_T^\infty \log(z)f(z)dz = \theta T^\theta\int_T^\infty\frac{\log(z)}{z^{\theta+1}}dz.$$

You can integrate by part (derivate $\log$ and integrate $z^{-1-\theta}$) and it comes:

$$I = \theta T^\theta \left(\left[\frac{\log (z)z^{-\theta}}{-\theta}\right]^\infty_T+\frac{1}{\theta}\int_T^\infty z^{-\theta-1}dz\right).$$

Finaly, you have:

$$I= \log(T)+\frac{1}{\theta}T^{-\theta}.$$

If you have $T=1$ as you simplified, you imediately have that:

$$I = \frac{1}{\theta}.$$

Hope it helps!